# Applying a mathematical operation across all columns in a .csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a to perform a mathematical operation across 100+ columns in a .csv file. Right now i can only apply this operation on a single column. How can I do this?

```
import csv
import numpy as np
with open ('file.csv','rU') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    arr=[]
    for col in reader:
        arr.append(float(col[0]))

    with open('/file.csv','w') as f:
        fn=['col0']
        writer=csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=fn)
        chunks=[arr[x:x+66] for x in xrange(0, len(arr), 66)]
        group = []
        for i in range(len(chunks)):
            grp=chunks[i]
            grp=grp[6:]
            group.append(grp)
        flat_group = []
        for x in range(len(group)):
            for y in range(len(group[x])):
                flat_group.append(group[x][y])
        avg = []
        unflattened_grp = zip(*[iter(flat_group)]*6)
        for z in range(len(unflattened_grp)):
            avrg = sum(unflattened_grp[z])/len(unflattened_grp[z])
            avg.append(avrg)
        for row in avg:
            writer.writerow({'col0':row})
```

Comment: Aside: if you're doing math on tabular data, [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) would make your life much easier.

Comment: Can you store the entire input file in memory? If not, then I would suggest creating a temporary csv file with all the data for a column in each row.

Comment: I guess, but my only obstacle is to apply this to every column. these are huge data files which are only going to get bigger so theres no way but to automate that part.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the entire input file into memory, transpose the rows and columns, and then either apply the mathematical operation to each row of data in the transposed array or write it to another .csv file for further processing a row-at-a-time.

```
import csv

with open('numbers.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    arr = [tuple(float(v) for v in row) for row in reader]

arr = zip(*arr)  # transpose rows and columns

with open('transposed_numbers.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(arr)

print('done')
```

Sample input file:

```
0,1,2,3,4     
5,6,7,8,9     
10,11,12,13,14
```

Sample output file:

```
0.0,5.0,10.0
1.0,6.0,11.0
2.0,7.0,12.0
3.0,8.0,13.0
4.0,9.0,14.0
```

Another, much slower option, would be to read the input file multiple times, processing a different column each iteration. This is an example of a classic speed vs memory-usage trade-off.